# Generate CREATE TABLE script from SELECT statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

The problem is that:
In SQL Server,I have a SELECT statement that might take any form like

```
SELECT ID,Name
FROM Table1;
```

Or

```
SELECT ID,Name
FROM Table1
WHERE ID IN(
SELECT ID
FROM Table2
WHERE City = 'C1'
)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT ID,Name
  FROM Tablex
  INTERSECT
  SELECT ID,Name
  FROM Tablex
) AS T
```

or whatever sql statement that might be very complex, and I need to generate the CREATE TABLE statement that creates a table with a structure that can hold the data of the result set returned by the SELECT statement.

The code can be C# or T-SQL.

**EDIT:**

The SELECT statement is a parameter passed to my application.The SELECT statement usually returns millions of records that will be transferred from a server to another so I need the CREATE TABLE script to be executed on the destination server to which the data will be transferred.

Comment: From `C#` you could execute `SET FMTONLY  ON; YourQuery` though not sure how to consume the results of that. Think it just sends back an empty result set.

Comment: You can do this with SqlDataReader's GetSchemaTable() plus SqlBulkCopy. It's tedious but should work. Also SELECT INTO should work if you can link the servers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my try inspired from the comments on my question, and many thanks to everybody:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=myserver;database=mydb;user id=sa;password=mypassword;"))
            {

                Console.WriteLine(GetCreateTableFromSqlCode(@"
SELECT ID,Eid,Keyword AS Keywords,KeywordType AS Sources,Year
FROM Eid_Keywords 
WHERE Eid IN(SELECT Eid FROM ReviewersPublications)","Keywords",con));                

            }
        }

        public static string GetCreateTableFromSqlCode(string sqlSelect,string tableName, SqlConnection con)
        {            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SET FMTONLY ON;\r\n{0}\r\nSET FMTONLY OFF;",sqlSelect), con);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                reader.Close();
                return GetCreateTableScript(dt, tableName);

            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Close();
            }

        }

        private static string GetCreateTableScript(DataTable dt,string tableName)
        {
            string snip = string.Empty;
            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
            sql.AppendFormat("CREATE TABLE {0}\r\n(\r\n",tableName);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
                snip = GetColumnSql(dr);
                sql.AppendFormat((i < dt.Rows.Count - 1) ? snip : snip.TrimEnd(',','\r','\n'));
            }
            sql.AppendFormat("\r\n)");
            return sql.ToString();
        }


        private static string GetColumnSql(DataRow dr)
        {
            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
            sql.AppendFormat("\t[{0}] {1}{2} {3} {4},\r\n",
                dr["ColumnName"].ToString(),
                dr["DataTypeName"].ToString(),
                (HasSize(dr["DataTypeName"].ToString())) ? "(" + dr["ColumnSize"].ToString() + ")" : (HasPrecisionAndScale(dr["DataTypeName"].ToString())) ? "(" + dr["NumericPrecision"].ToString() + "," + dr["NumericScale"].ToString() + ")" : "",
                (dr["IsIdentity"].ToString() == "true") ? "IDENTITY" : "",
                (dr["AllowDBNull"].ToString() == "true") ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL");
            return sql.ToString();
        }

        private static bool HasSize(string dataType)
        {            
            Dictionary<string, bool> dataTypes = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            dataTypes.Add("bigint", false);
            dataTypes.Add("binary", true);
            dataTypes.Add("bit", false);
            dataTypes.Add("char", true);
            dataTypes.Add("date", false);
            dataTypes.Add("datetime", false);
            dataTypes.Add("datetime2", false);
            dataTypes.Add("datetimeoffset", false);
            dataTypes.Add("decimal", false);
            dataTypes.Add("float", false);
            dataTypes.Add("geography", false);
            dataTypes.Add("geometry", false);
            dataTypes.Add("hierarchyid", false);
            dataTypes.Add("image", true);
            dataTypes.Add("int", false);
            dataTypes.Add("money", false);
            dataTypes.Add("nchar", true);
            dataTypes.Add("ntext", true);
            dataTypes.Add("numeric", false);
            dataTypes.Add("nvarchar", true);
            dataTypes.Add("real", false);
            dataTypes.Add("smalldatetime", false);
            dataTypes.Add("smallint", false);
            dataTypes.Add("smallmoney", false);
            dataTypes.Add("sql_variant", false);
            dataTypes.Add("sysname", false);
            dataTypes.Add("text", true);
            dataTypes.Add("time", false);
            dataTypes.Add("timestamp", false);
            dataTypes.Add("tinyint", false);
            dataTypes.Add("uniqueidentifier", false);
            dataTypes.Add("varbinary", true);
            dataTypes.Add("varchar", true);
            dataTypes.Add("xml", false);
            if (dataTypes.ContainsKey(dataType))
                return dataTypes[dataType];
            return false;
        }

        private static bool HasPrecisionAndScale(string dataType)
        {
            Dictionary<string, bool> dataTypes = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            dataTypes.Add("bigint", false);
            dataTypes.Add("binary", false);
            dataTypes.Add("bit", false);
            dataTypes.Add("char", false);
            dataTypes.Add("date", false);
            dataTypes.Add("datetime", false);
            dataTypes.Add("datetime2", false);
            dataTypes.Add("datetimeoffset", false);
            dataTypes.Add("decimal", true);
            dataTypes.Add("float", true);
            dataTypes.Add("geography", false);
            dataTypes.Add("geometry", false);
            dataTypes.Add("hierarchyid", false);
            dataTypes.Add("image", false);
            dataTypes.Add("int", false);
            dataTypes.Add("money", false);
            dataTypes.Add("nchar", false);
            dataTypes.Add("ntext", false);
            dataTypes.Add("numeric", false);
            dataTypes.Add("nvarchar", false);
            dataTypes.Add("real", true);
            dataTypes.Add("smalldatetime", false);
            dataTypes.Add("smallint", false);
            dataTypes.Add("smallmoney", false);
            dataTypes.Add("sql_variant", false);
            dataTypes.Add("sysname", false);
            dataTypes.Add("text", false);
            dataTypes.Add("time", false);
            dataTypes.Add("timestamp", false);
            dataTypes.Add("tinyint", false);
            dataTypes.Add("uniqueidentifier", false);
            dataTypes.Add("varbinary", false);
            dataTypes.Add("varchar", false);
            dataTypes.Add("xml", false);
            if (dataTypes.ContainsKey(dataType))
                return dataTypes[dataType];
            return false;
        }



    }
```

Comment: Thanks - this helped me get some SQL create scripts from a remote server quickly and efficiently (I wanted some for local debugging and prototyping).

Comment: I did have to change my code here though to have the comparison use  "True"  instead of "true".                                                                    (dr["IsIdentity"].ToString() == "True") ? "IDENTITY" : "",
(dr["AllowDBNull"].ToString() == "True") ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL");

Comment: IsIdentity and AllowDBNull are both bool types, so just use cast.
As in: (bool)dr["IsIdentity"] ? "IDENTITY" : ""
The "true" vs "True" difference is probably due to local regional settings.

Comment: What a public service! Thanks for putting this together!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [common table expressions (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) or [table variables](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-table-variables).

EDIT: Yes, it seems I have wrong understanding of question. But maybe [SELECT .. INTO statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750.aspx) can help you? BOL says

> SELECT INTO can be used to combine data from several tables or views into one table. It can also be used to create a new table that contains data selected from a linked server.
>   The structure of the new table is defined by the attributes of the expressions in the select list.

Comment: -1 Neither of those constructs will help the stated goal as far as I can see. For table variables you need to know the columns first and defining a CTE doesn't solve the stated problem.

Comment: The problem with this is the performance as I mentioned before, existence of linked server and where to add the 'INTO tableName' phrase in a complex query like the before-mentioned or something like SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Year = 2000) AS Count2000 FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN(
SELECT ID
FROM Table2
WHERE City = 'C1'
);